# Vlookup, Total "No" Values per specific date

Tags: excel, count, vlookup, countif

How do I calculate the Total Number of cells containing "No" for the specified Date in Column 3, I need to do it as a summary table that will update as the days get added to the table:

23-Oct-16        1
24-Oct-16        0
25-Oct-16        1

[Table1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4qub.jpg)

Comment: I have used =countif(Cell Range, "no"), it gives me the correct value if the cell range is the specific date, I wanted to do a vlookup instead so I wouldnt have to re select a range for every date

Answer (score 0):

Make a "helper" column in your table, where you concatenate the date and the word No. Then you do the same in your summary table and in an additional column in the summary table you put your `sumifs()` formula with the concatenated cell in the summary table as the criteria and the entire concatenated column in the original table as the sum range.